# Python - Parsing data from table with uncertain attribute fields

Tags: python, dictionary, datatables

I am attempting to extract the data from a table output from another shell program via a python subprocess and the output is shown below. I have created a dictionary to house the data however I am running into issues where some of the table columns are empty, to which in that case I want to populate the value for that key as just 'empty'.

instantiated dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'timestamp': '', 'ID': '', 'count(a)' : '', 'count(b)' : '',
            'count(c)' : '', 'count(d)' : ''}
```

table example outputted from another utility:

```
   utc                          ID     count(a)   count(b)  count(c)    count(d)
    2019-07-02 20:15:50.766868  115     274        390                     4                                            
    2019-07-03 03:33:19.784049  115     274, 333   390       366                                 
    2019-07-03 03:33:20.635242  115     274        390                                                  
    2019-07-03 03:33:21.581050  115     366        390       0
    2019-07-03 03:35:20.061389  115     366        390                                                      
    2019-07-03 03:35:20.062680  115     366        390                     7
```

I am splitting the output by a new line character initially to look at each row:

```
temp_split = str(self.event_output).split('\n')
```

The number of spaces are not guaranteed so I have attempted to split for more than 1 space (count(a) has an example of having a single space), as well as attempting to split by tabs:

```
for item in temp_split:
    data_split = re.split(r"\s{2,}|\t", item)
```

As you can probably tell, the issue that I am running into is that because I am splitting by spaces, those columns with no value at all are completely skipped over. I have tried to set values as such, but i am getting an indexoutofrange error because those empty items are skipped over:

```
redundancy_dict['timestamp'] = data_split[0]
redundancy_dict['id'] = data_split[1]
redundancy_dict['counta'] = data_split[2]
redundancy_dict['countb'] = data_split[3]
redundancy_dict['countc'] = data_split[4]
redundancy_dict['countd'] = data_split[5]
```